# r setting the size of a png device to the grob size

Tags: r, grob

I have created a tableGrob `T`, this tableGrob can be of an altering size, according to previously given parameters.

Is there a way to use the `png()` function so that the width and height parameters will be taken from the previously created tableGrob

Lets say something like this:

```
library(gridExtra)

T=tableGrob(mydata)

 png("myfile"
 ,width=convertX(grobWidth(T),"points")    # pseudo-code
 ,height=convertX(grobHeight(T),"points"))
 grid.draw(T)
 dev.off
```

I get a message that r cannot start the png device and about 50 warnings.

Answer (score 1):

We can set this up using `sum()` nested within the `convertHeight` and `convertWidth` mehods in the `grid` package:

```
grobHeight <- function(x) {
  grid::convertHeight(sum(x$heights), "in", TRUE)
}

grobWidth <- function(x) {
  grid::convertWidth(sum(x$widths), "in", TRUE)
}


png("myfile"
    ,width  = grobWidth(T)
    ,height = grobHeight(T)
      )
```

Comment: trying this I'm getting 'font family not found warnings

Comment: @Saar I can't replicate that, but I don't think it sounds related. If you think I'm wrong we can troubleshoot the reproducibility in SO chat

Comment: Hi @hack-R 7 , I'm rather new to R and therefore am not able to tell exactly whether it is related or not. I will gladly put a larger piece of my code wherever you want (BTW what is SO chat?) so we'll be able to keep troubleshooting.

Comment: @saar SO is short for Stack Overflow. They have a chat we can use for extended discussions (I should give you a link... I'll get back to you on that)

Comment: I have not had the time to chase that in the last two weeks, and it seems that so have you, I'm getting the follwing warnings:  In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  font family not found in Windows font database.             It happens both on a pdf and a png device.

Comment: Update:  works beautifully on pdf, but not in png. Warnings are still there in both graphic devices.

Comment: gsave("test.tiff", width = grobWidth(tab1), height = grobHeight(tab1)) Worked for me, thank you!